# Переход на сайт

Tags: php, html, mysql, auth, site

Проблема заключается в том что при вводе пароля сайт не переходит на другую страницу(способ перехода header)

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head><title>Авторизация</title></head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="registr.php">
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Логин</td><td><input type="text" name="login"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Пароль</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="Submit" value="Вход"></td><td></td></tr>
</table> </form> </body> </html>
```

registr.php

```
<php?
$login_user=“admin”;
$password_user=“admin”;
$login=$POST[‘login’];
$password=$POST[‘password’];
if( ($login_user == $login) and ($password_user == $password) )
{
header(“Location: http://www.music-5a.ml/my/boria385/boria385.html”);
exit;
}
else
{
echo “Не правильный логин или пароль”;
}
?>
```

Comment: Это весь текст registr.php? Убедитесь, что до строки `header(...)` нигде нет вывода тегов html или команд echo и всяких там print и print_r. А также, что строка с заголовком начинается в самом начале строки и перед ней нет пробелов и табуляций. Запросы как раз могут быть ))

Answer (score 0):

Если вкратце, то Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы обращаетесь к `$POST` тогда как нужно обращаться к `$_POST` (если конечно Вы не пишите на `PHP v3` :) )

Но на меня тут что-то нашло, и я слегка `извратил` Ваш код, надеюсь Вы меня за это простите :)

```php
<?php
//Выставляем логи и пароль пользователя-администратора 
//лучше конечно такие вещи хранить в отдельном конфигурационном файле 
//и подключать его через `include`, 'require' или `require_once`
//для того, чтобы в случае надобности поправить их там, а не искать 
//везде по скриптам
$admin = array('login' => 'admin', 'password' => 'admin123');

//Выставляем флаг `is_admin` по-умолчанию в `0`
$is_admin = 0;

//Проверяем, что нам что-то пришло методом POST
//для всех данных отправленных данным методом в PHP есть глобальная пемеренная массив - $_POST
if ( count( $_POST ) > 0 ) {
    foreach( $admin as $key => $value ) {
        //Проверяем, что в массиве $_POST нам пришли переменные с теми же
        //названиями, что и в массиве `$admin`
        //и что их значение совпадает с теми же, что и в `$admin`
        //если `ДА` - увеличиваем счетчик совпадений
        $is_admin += ( isset( $_POST[ $key ] ) && $_POST[ $key ] == $value ? 1 : 0 );
    }
    //Проверяем, если счетчик совпадений равен кол-ву элментов в массиве $admin - значит это пользователь-администратор
    if ( $is_admin == count( $admin ) ) {
        header("Location: http://www.music-5a.ml/my/boria385/boria385.html");
    }
    //Иначе снова показываем страницу авторизации с сообщением об ошибке "Неправильный логин или пароль"

}
```